# USB MSC with STM32Cube

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-mass-storage

I'm using STM32Cube to generate simple USB MSC project. I'm using STM32F417VG.
So I'm selecting `USB_OTG_FS` - Device_only and `USB_DEVICE` - Class For FS IP - Mass Storage Class.
Then I'm generating source code, compile it and download to board, put it's USB cable to PC and nothing happens.
*What am I doing wrong?*

Answer (score 4):

The STM32Cube application helps you get started on developing an application, but does not do the work for you. The generated code will include all the libraries necessary and initialize the hardware so that all the functions you selected are available and ready to go, and then begin an empty infinite loop. It will not show any outward behavior or respond to any external stimulus.

You will need to add some of your own code for the microcontroller to actually do anything.

If you are unsure what you need to do to make the USB functions work, take a look at the example projects that come with STM32Cube and the documentation comments in the library files it included in your project.

However, even a "simple" USB project can be relatively complex, and an unresponsive microcontroller can be mystifying. You may want to get your bearings with very simple GPIO-type projects. Making an LED blink is a microcontroller's "Hello World".

Comment: I am interested whether STM32Cube is enough "serious" to use its generated code "as is" or it is only demonstration and example?